# how to create model in mvc3 using massive db for a DB table with composite primary key?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, composite-primary-key, massive

Im new to massive ORM. Im working in asp .net mvc3 and using massive ORM. I have a table with composite primary and I need to create model for the same. Can anyone tell me how to do this? I had created model for tables with single primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Generally composite keys aren't a good idea from a DBA perspective. This is very arguable, of course, but generally throwing a UNIQUE constraint down on the two columns of interest and having that identified by a PK is what many people do these days.

Other than that - nothing is built in.